# PySpark str.title(): 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want the first letter in all rows of a particular column to be capitalized.

`df['Name'] = df.Name.str.title()`

But I keep getting the error 'Column' object is not callable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are doing it wrong, pyspark is bit different from pandas.

do the follow:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import initcap, col

df.withColumn('Name', initcap(col('Name'))
```

Reference: https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/convert-to-upper-case-lower-case-and-title-case-in-pyspark/